# How to change from jQuery to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".normalText").css("border", "0px solid green");
```

How would you replace this jQuery statement with a plain JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: i didn't get you, can you please elaborate some more

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName( className );` for modern browsers only, otherwise there's no javascript replacement to get elements by className.

Comment: @Mithun P: It sounds like he wants vanilla JavaScript functions to replace the jQuery ones (I know, right?!)

Answer (score 3):

To get a NodeList containing all elements with `class="normalText"`, you could use:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('normalText');
```

And then loop through them:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('normalText'),
    len = els.length;
while (len--) {
  els[len].style.border = '3px solid hotpink';
}
```

`getElementsByClassName` isn’t supported in [some older browsers](http://caniuse.com/getElementsByClassName). If support is an issue, you could use a fallback like [this](http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/) or [this](http://www.dustindiaz.com/getelementsbyclass/).

On the other hand, if you’re only supporting modern browsers, you might as well use `querySelectorAll` and `Array#forEach`:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.normalText'), function(el) {
  el.style.border = '3px solid hotpink';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For modern browsers you can use the [`.getElementsByClassName()` method <sup>MDC docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('normalText');
```

for more modern you can use the [`.querySelectorAll()` method <sup>MDC docs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.normalText');
```

for older browsers you can do (*taken from http://robertnyman.com/2005/11/07/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname/*)

```
function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
    var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && oElm.all)? oElm.all : oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
    var arrReturnElements = new Array();
    strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\\-");
    var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strClassName + "(\\s|$)");
    var oElement;
    for(var i=0; i<arrElements.length; i++){
        oElement = arrElements[i];
        if(oRegExp.test(oElement.className)){
            arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
        }
    }
    return (arrReturnElements)
}
```

and call it with

```
getElementsByClassName(document, "*", "normalText");
```

Comment: `document.querySelector` will only return the first matched element.

Comment: @Mathias, so true.. had the `querySelectorAll` in mind ... thanks for catching it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('normalText').style.border = '0px solid green';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like this built-in into Javascript as far as I know (edit: actually there's getElementsByClassName which works in some browsers only).

I guess your best chance is to write a function which loops through each DOM element and compares the class field with its argument.